# Convert a set to a vector of vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to convert  `unordered_set<string>` to `vector<vector<int>>`

The set contains `("1,2,2","1","1,2","2","2,2")`, and each element is a string. 
I would like to output a `vector<vector<int>>` containing

```
[
  [2],
  [1],
  [1,2,2],
  [2,2],
  [1,2],
  []
]
```

So how would I parse each element (string) and make it looks like the above scheme?

```
#define SSTR( x ) dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >( \
        ( std::ostringstream() << std::dec << x ) ).str()

vector<vector<int> > subsetsWithDup(const vector<int> &num) {
    unordered_set<string> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++)
    {
        result.insert(SSTR(num[i]));
        for (int j = i+1; j < num.size(); j++)
        {
            string d = SSTR(num[i]) + "," +SSTR(num[j]);
            result.insert(d);
        }
    }

    string lastString= "";
    for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++)
    {
        if ( i == num.size() -1)
        {
            lastString+= SSTR(num[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            lastString+= SSTR(num[i])+",";
        }
    }

    result.insert(lastString);

    // convert result back to vector<vector<int>>
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I can't tell what order you want them in -- it seems totally random!

Comment: the order is not imporant

Comment: So you provided an algorithm: I don't understand what you want us to do. Prove that it's correct? Take it through a debugger and see what the output is.

Comment: I can't convert the result(set) to a vector of vector of int. I need a clever way to parse each element string then put it in a vector

Comment: Why using `set<string>` instead of `set<vector<int>>` ?

Comment: how would I use the set with a vector<int> ? I'm beginner in c++

Comment: Your code takes `vector<int>` as input. In the middle, it converts those values to parts of a string (why?). You are asking how to convert the data you (for no reason I can think of) converted to a string back to a vector of integers? From the the code, it appears your code generates the power set of the incoming `vector<int>`. Why don't you just directly generate the power set, instead of going through a `string` in the middle? Imagine if someone asked how to separate sugar from flour. You ask why, and they give you a recipe that reads "mix sugar and flour. Then separate." What do you answer?

Comment: @Yakk It's from the word document which he printed out in order to scan it so that he could do OCR on it.

Comment: how would I refine my solution to a set of vector<int> > ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to validate your `string`s you can do a `transform` to construct the `vector<vector<int>>`:

```
set<string> foo{ "1,2,2", "1", "1,2", "2", "2,2" };
vector<vector<int>> bar(foo.size());

transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), [](const string& i){
    vector<int> result;
    auto it = const_cast<char*>(i.c_str());

    for (result.push_back(static_cast<int>(strtol(it, &it, 10)));
         it < i.c_str() + i.size();
         result.push_back(static_cast<int>(strtol(++it, &it, 10))));
    return result;
});
```

The lambda in the transform will step through the `string`:

1. Start `it` at the beginning of the `string`
2. Using `strtol` to extract each number
3. Pushing each number into `result`
4. Stepping over each `','` with `++it`
5. Return the constructed `result`

**Prerequisites:** This lambda assumes that your input `set` doesn't contain:

- An empty `string`
- A `string` that begins or ends with a comma (as in `"1,2,"`)
- A `string` that has consecutive commas (as in `"1,,2"`)
- That the string contains *only* contains digits and commas

**Note:** As a general rule a `const_cast` is bad so I wanted to comment on why I'm making one. Note that `*it` is never written to, only `it` is written to. So this is not violating the `const`-ness of `const string& i`. An alternative to `strtol` that doesn't require a `const_cast` is `stoi`, but until we get `string_view` from C++14 we'll need to construct a new `string` at each comma, so that's dreadfully inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution can be:

```
vector<string> split (string str, string seq) {
        vector<string> ret {};
        size_t pos {};

        while ((pos = str.find (seq)) != string::npos) {
            ret.push_back (str.substr (0, pos));
            str = str.substr (pos+seq.size ());
        }
        ret.push_back (str);

        return ret;
}

vector<int> to_vec_int (vector<string>&& vec) {
        vector<int> ret {};

        for (const auto& v : vec) {
                ret.push_back (stoi (v));
        }
        return ret;
}

int main () {
        unordered_set<string> st {"1,2,2","1","1,2","2","2,2"};
        vector<vector<int>> vec {};
        for (const auto& s : st) {
                vec.push_back (to_vec_int (split (s, ",")));
        }

        for (const auto& v : vec) {
                for (const auto& s : v) {
                        cout << s << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Since your elements are delimited by comma, we can split them using split () function and we get vector of strings. This vector has to be converted to vector of int, which is the reason of existence of to_vec_int ().

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution using istringstream to find the commas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <sstream>

void main()
{
    using namespace std;
    unordered_set<string> strSet;
    strSet.insert("1,2,2");
    strSet.insert("1");
    strSet.insert("1,2");
    strSet.insert("2");
    strSet.insert("2,2");
    vector<int> nums;
    vector<vector<int>> arr_of_nums;

    for (const auto &str : strSet) {
        istringstream strStream(str);
        string strToInt;
        while (getline(strStream, strToInt, ',')) {
            nums.push_back(stoi(strToInt));
        }
        arr_of_nums.push_back(nums);
        nums.clear();
    }
    for(const auto &nums : arr_of_nums) {
        for (const auto &num : nums) {
            cout << num << ",";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```